# Why does this element not render in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, web

The following HTML/CSS code is rendering in IE (Version 8) but not in Firefox (Version 25)

Any reason why?

HTML:

```
<img class="buttonmini" id="btn_Actual_Effort" onclick="showEffortDetail()"    disabled="disabled">
```

CSS:

```
.buttonmini
{
    background: url(../newimages/effort_calendar.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana; /*font-size: 8pt;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: how can you have an img tag without a src attribute? or for an even better question, why would you want that?

Comment: @sevenseacat I believe the background property in CSS covers for it.  Also, this is not my code so I don't know why the 'src' attribute was not specified.

Comment: if that does work in other browsers, I believe it is in error. Why would you not just set the src to be the image you want to display, so the image actually has meaning without styling?

Comment: @sevenseacat This is not my code, so I am not sure about the why part of your your question.

Comment: "I believe the background property in CSS covers for it." It does not.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Thanks.  I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Right; or more in general: the HTML contains an error. Different browsers respond differently to errors. In this case, IE shows it, FF does not, yet other browsers make demons fly out of your nose. Mystery solved.

Comment: @MrLister even though src is a "required" attribute, shouldn't the tag be able to "break" gracefully by simply reverting to an element of the same type?

Comment: @Enigmadan No, it shouldn't. It doesn't have to! `<img>` elements are meant to show images, through their `src` attributes. That's all they do. They don't have to do anything else. Because if you want to do something else, you can use a different element!

Comment: There's a bug filed for this:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

It can be fixed if you add a `display: inline-block` in your css.

#### Longer answer:

It also renders in Webkit based browsers (Chrome and Safari at least).

This seems to occur because Firefox does not interpret image tags the same way as other browsers.

The `<img>` tag is [defined](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html) by w3 as an inline-block element.

When the image's source is included in the tag (e.g. `<img src="thisIsMyImage.jpg">`), Firefox interprets it correctly (as an inline-block element).
However, when there is no `src` available immediately in the tag, Firefox appears to interpret it solely as an inline element. This means you cannot define it's width or height.

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuNhr/3/) for some experimentation with different ways of getting the background of an `<img>` tag to display.

Comment: @Enigmadan Actually, the correct rendering here (the one the HTML spec calls for) is the Firefox one, not the WebKit/IE one.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Ahh. Thank you! Do you have a source for correctness? I read several versions of the spec, but none of them really explained the display-type of img to my liking.

Comment: @Enigmadan http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013OctDec/0294.html has the relevant spec links and quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In an `img` element, the `src` attribute is required by HTML specifications. If you omit it, the rendering and behavior of the element is undefined. (It may work with some browsers the way you want, and you might trick some other browsers to do the same, but any new version of a browser could break things down.)

Thus, use a content image (an `img` element with `src` attribute and adequate `alt` attribute), instead of a background image on an `img` element.